# Turning file from FTP server to byte array for client

Tags: c++, ftp, byte

I am trying to get the byte array of my file in my FTP server. I want to do this without saving the file to disk. I am really stuck on what to do.

I've been looking around on GitHub and different places.

Comment: You can't do it without downloading the file. Do you mean without saving the file to disk?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to save it to the disk. Maybe download it to memory?

Comment: There is nothing in C++ itself for this. You need an FTP library, preferably one that allows you to download to memory. There are many 3rd party libraries available, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried https://github.com/embeddedmz/ftpclient-cpp. I think I should just grab information straight off of my forum/database instead of FTP since I heard it was more secure.

Comment: You're probably smart to consider avoiding FTP.  You might look at `SCP`, `SFTP`, or `WebDAV` / `http`.  It shouldn't be too difficult to find a client library that provides the remote file as a stream or as a series of callbacks that allow you to assemble the file in memory.

Comment: Yep, I've been looking into libcurl and I think I've found what I need.